# Spoj :ENIGMATH - PLAY WITH MATH

Tags: c++, algorithm

Why am i getting time limit  exceeded in this question? link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ENIGMATH/

lcm is easily calculated with the help of gcd of two numbers.For calculating the gcd euclid's algorithm is used.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long long int gcd(long long int a,long long int b)
{
     if(b==0)
     return a;

     else
     return gcd(b,a%b);
}
int main()
{
    long long int t,a,b,lcm,i=0;
    cin>>t;

    while(i<t)
    {
      cin>>a>>b;
      if(a==b)
      cout<<"1 1\n";

      else
      {
          lcm=(a*b)/gcd(a,b);
          cout<<lcm/a<<" "<<lcm/b<<"\n";
      }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating `i` in the loop, so it will fail into an infinite loop unless you enter negative value or zero to `t`.

Try having it updated by changing `i<t` to `i++<t` or another manner you like.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this Way... Thank You.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long long int gcd(long long int a,long long int b)
{
     if(b==0)
     return a;

     else
     return gcd(b,a%b);
}
int main()
{
    long long int t,a,b,lcm,i=0;
    cin>>t;

    while(i<t)
    {
      cin>>a>>b;
      if(a==b)
      cout<<"1 1\n";

      else
      {
          lcm=(a*b)/gcd(a,b);
          cout<<lcm/a<<" "<<lcm/b<<"\n";
      }
     i += 1;//Here was mistook.
 }
 return 0;
}
```